# How to get the string form of MultipartRequest that has file in it in Flutter

Tags: flutter, encryption, signature, form-data, hmacsha256

So i got a test to make a Flutter app that sent requests to a rest API. But the api requires a signature that is generated by combining *path + request body + timestamp + token* then `encrypt` it with `HMAC-Sha256` and then `base64-encoded` it.

The problem is there is one `POST` endpoint that needs a file. But, there is no clear way how to get the raw string of the `MultipartRequest`.

I tried to use the  `await request.finalize().toBytes()` and then wrapped it in `utf.decode()`, i got and error `FormatException: invalid utf-8`.

And also I have tried to used `FormData` class from `dio` package. Still unclear how to get the raw string that being sent if it has file in it.

I tried the same thing i did which is use functions that is equivalent to get the bytes and `utf8.decode` it. Still go the same error.

So does anyone know how to get the raw string by `MultipartRequest`, `FormData` or by any class that can send file over http?

Edit 08-12-2023:

Since people are requested to add the spec of the payload to generate the signature, here they are:

The payload consists of a path, verb, token, timestamp, and request body.

Example:
`path=/ping&verb=GET&token=Bearer R04XSUbnm1GXNmDiXx9ysWMpFWBr×&timestamp=2019-01-02T13:14:15.678Z&body=`

Detail every element of the payload:

1. Path

The value in the path is the URL after the hostname, port, and `/api` (if any) without Query Parameters.
example:
from {URL}/api/ping?version=1

```
becomes /ping
```

2. Verb

is HTTP methods that are in uppercase.

```
example:
GET, POST, PUT, PATCH, and DELETE.
```

3. Token

The token that is used for the Authorization header. (starts with 'Bearer').

```
example:
Bearer R04XSUbnm1GXNmDiXx9ysWMpFWBr

Note: Don't forget to add the Bearer before the Token
```

4. Timestamp

Timestamp when you call the API. The Timestamp format must follow the ISO8601 format (yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.SSSZ) and must be in zero UTC offset.

```
example:
2022-11-11T07:13:06.648Z

Note: Timestamp must be in UTC or GMT +0 timezone format.
```

5. body

Request body sent for API Call.

```
Example: 
&body={"hello":"world"} If there is no request body, such as a GET hit, then leave blank. &body=

Note: Be aware that you must enter the exact body you sent. Because differences in letters, spaces, and lines can cause differences in the signature.
```

Comment: What do you mean by "But, there is no clear way how to get the raw string of the MultipartRequest." Do you mean you want to send String data as part of the request?

Comment: @TrueKing Yes, i need the string data version of the request so that i could make a valid signature with it.

Comment: You could simply built the body of the multipart request yourself - it's a pretty simple format. Do you have a spec for how to compute this hash? It really should be clear about what it means by "request body" when using a multipart form.

Answer (score 0):

It's actually really easy to get the body of a multipart request, using the same code that the real multipart request does. (See http's multipart_request.dart.)

Unfortunately, you need to copy some boilerplate into your own code:

```
class DummyRequest {
  late final String contentType;

  /// The form fields to send for this request.
  final fields = <String, String>{};

  /// The list of files to upload for this request.
  final files = <http.MultipartFile>[];

  Future<Uint8List> finalize() async {
    final boundary = _boundaryString();
    contentType = 'multipart/form-data; boundary=$boundary';
    final stream = _finalize(boundary);
    final bb = BytesBuilder();
    for (final b in await stream.toList()) {
      bb.add(b);
    }
    return bb.toBytes();
  }

  Stream<List<int>> _finalize(String boundary) async* {
    const line = [13, 10]; // \r\n
    final separator = utf8.encode('--$boundary\r\n');
    final close = utf8.encode('--$boundary--\r\n');

    for (var field in fields.entries) {
      yield separator;
      yield utf8.encode(_headerForField(field.key, field.value));
      yield utf8.encode(field.value);
      yield line;
    }

    for (final file in files) {
      yield separator;
      yield utf8.encode(_headerForFile(file));
      yield* file.finalize();
      yield line;
    }
    yield close;
  }

  /// Returns the header string for a field.
  ///
  /// The return value is guaranteed to contain only ASCII characters.
  String _headerForField(String name, String value) {
    var header =
        'content-disposition: form-data; name="${_browserEncode(name)}"';
    if (!isPlainAscii(value)) {
      header = '$header\r\n'
          'content-type: text/plain; charset=utf-8\r\n'
          'content-transfer-encoding: binary';
    }
    return '$header\r\n\r\n';
  }

  /// Returns the header string for a file.
  ///
  /// The return value is guaranteed to contain only ASCII characters.
  String _headerForFile(http.MultipartFile file) {
    var header = 'content-type: ${file.contentType}\r\n'
        'content-disposition: form-data; name="${_browserEncode(file.field)}"';

    if (file.filename != null) {
      header = '$header; filename="${_browserEncode(file.filename!)}"';
    }
    return '$header\r\n\r\n';
  }

  /// Encode [value] in the same way browsers do.
  String _browserEncode(String value) =>
      // http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2388 mandates some complex encodings for
// field names and file names, but in practice user agents seem not to
// follow this at all. Instead, they URL-encode `\r`, `\n`, and `\r\n` as
// `\r\n`; URL-encode `"`; and do nothing else (even for `%` or non-ASCII
// characters). We follow their behavior.
      value.replaceAll(_newlineRegExp, '%0D%0A').replaceAll('"', '%22');

  /// Returns a randomly-generated multipart boundary string
  String _boundaryString() {
    var prefix = 'dart-http-boundary-';
    var list = List<int>.generate(
        _boundaryLength - prefix.length,
        (index) =>
            boundaryCharacters[_random.nextInt(boundaryCharacters.length)],
        growable: false);
    return '$prefix${String.fromCharCodes(list)}';
  }

  static const int _boundaryLength = 70;
  static final Random _random = Random();
}

/// A regular expression that matches strings that are composed entirely of
/// ASCII-compatible characters.
final _asciiOnly = RegExp(r'^[\x00-\x7F]+$');

/// Returns whether [string] is composed entirely of ASCII-compatible
/// characters.
bool isPlainAscii(String string) => _asciiOnly.hasMatch(string);

final _newlineRegExp = RegExp(r'\r\n|\r|\n');

const List<int> boundaryCharacters = <int>[
  43,
  95,
  45,
  46,
  48,
  49,
  50,
  51,
  52,
  53,
  54,
  55,
  56,
  57,
  65,
  66,
  67,
  68,
  69,
  70,
  71,
  72,
  73,
  74,
  75,
  76,
  77,
  78,
  79,
  80,
  81,
  82,
  83,
  84,
  85,
  86,
  87,
  88,
  89,
  90,
  97,
  98,
  99,
  100,
  101,
  102,
  103,
  104,
  105,
  106,
  107,
  108,
  109,
  110,
  111,
  112,
  113,
  114,
  115,
  116,
  117,
  118,
  119,
  120,
  121,
  122
];
```

Which you now use like this:

```
  final rq = DummyRequest()
    ..fields['foo'] = 'bar'
    ..files.add(http.MultipartFile.fromBytes('someFile', Uint8List(10)));

  final bytes = await rq.finalize();
  final contentType = rq.contentType;
```

Hold onto those bytes and content type. Use the bytes in your hash and the bytes and content type in your actual request. You must set the content type of your actual request with:

```
headers['content-type'] = contentType;
```

as that has the randomly generated boundary chars saved in it.

However - and this is a big one - the bytes will contain binary, non-printable chars if the file(s) you include are not just all ascii.

You didn't include all of the spec in your edited question. You are meant to minify and hash the body as follows:

```
The body when sending an API request. Lowercase(HexEncode(SHA-256(minify(RequestBody))))

Example: {"hello": "world"}

Result SHA256 : a47a5f14b3e78b5e3d3f81b1a1468499be964660f818c10adcac792c42709749
```

Lower case is easy, hex encode is easy, sha-256 is easy, but what does `minify` do - and can it accept binary chars?

Comment: Ok thanks, but I've no idea why you answered it tbh. The test is over and go an offer eventhough I'm not completed that bit of the test. BUT after I hear they said that the company will hold my diploma when I started join there (for some reason) I immediately rejected it because I'm still currently have a job and didn't want to change it to the job that probably will really withhold me if I'm going to jump ship.